# Lose css when try to redirect the page in spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

this is my first web application and I am trying to build it using spring mvc. However, I have constantly experienced that css doesn't apply constantly when I try to redirect the page.

I have a controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/budget", method=RequestMethod.GET )
public String showBudgetPage() {
    LOGGER.info("Show Budget Page");            // Display budget page.
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return "budget";
}
```

The page will style with the css. However, when I try to redirect the page with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/budget", method=RequestMethod.GET )
public String showBudgetPage() {
    LOGGER.info("Show Budget Page");            // Display budget page.
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return "redirect:/" + String.valueOf(year) + "/budget";
    //return "redirect:" + String.valueOf(year) + "/budget";

}


@RequestMapping(value="/{year}/budget", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showBudgetPageByYear(Model model,
                @PathVariable("year") int year) {
    LOGGER.info("Show Budget Page");
    return "budget";
}
```

The page completely return to it original state with white background and black front. May any one suggest me why it happens? How should I prevent it and similar case in the future? Many thanks.